# Preg Match to find % in textbox value

Tags: php

i have a textbox value 
i have to find out the % symbol in the textvalue
can anyone suggest me how to do that ?

i have a textbox that contains some value and i have to find out whether that textbox contain % symbol or not

```
$camp_ttllimpression=$_POST['camp_ttllimpression'];
$camp_ttllclicks=$_POST['camp_ttllclicks'];
$camp_ttlleads=$_POST['camp_ttlleads'];
$camp_ttllsales=$_POST['camp_ttllsales'];
$hid=$_POST['hid'];
$camp_cpa_amnt=$_POST['camp_cpa_amnt'];
$camp_cpm_amnt=$_POST['camp_cpm_amnt'];
$camp_cpc_amnt=$_POST['camp_cpc_amnt'];
$camp_cpl_amnt=$_POST['camp_cpl_amnt'];
$camp_cpm_budgt=($camp_ttllimpression * $camp_cpm_amnt)/1000;
$camp_cpc_budgt=$camp_ttllclicks * $camp_cpc_amnt;
$camp_cpl_budgt=$camp_ttlleads * $camp_cpl_amnt;
$camp_cpa_budgt=$camp_ttllsales * $camp_cpa_amnt;
if($hid=="%") { echo Open;} else { echo $camp_cpa_budgt;}
```

Comment: Do you mean "% is somewhere in the text of that textbox" or "% is the only content of that textbox"?

Answer (score 1):

Substitute the correct key for `$_POST['textfield']` since it isn't clear from your question.  `preg_match()` is not needed-- this is better done with simple string operations.

```
// To find out if it contains a % anywhere...
if (strpos($_POST['texfield'], '%') !== FALSE) {
   // Contais a %
}

// To find out if it contains only a %
if ($_POST['texfield'] === '%') {
   // Contains only %
}
```

Comment: `strpos(…) !== FALSE`, otherwise it will return 0 (falsy) for the first char in the string

Comment: Your `strpos` condition is wrong. If position is `0` then it is treated as false. Use `strpos(...) !== false`

Answer (score 1):

I don't get your question completly but hope you want something like this ,
Use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

`if(strpos($hid,"%") !== false )`

Comment: Your `strpos` condition is wrong. If position is `0` then it is treated as false. Use `strpos(...) !== false`

Comment: Same comment as for Michael: `strpos(…) !== FALSE`, otherwise it will not work for the first position of the string